# Deleting LrsActivityProvider Deletion causing issue in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, scorm, scorm-cloud-api

I am trying to delete LrsActivity provider its working in all browsers but not in chrome can anybody help me below lie of code causing issue in chrome

```
XmlDocument response = request.CallService("rustici.lrsaccount.deleteActivityProvider");
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? `LrsActivity` gives only two results on Google

Comment: This appears to be a SCORM Cloud specific query. If that's the case I'd recommend contacting support@scorm.com and they'll assist you.